# Cordova Android application has touch issues on Samsung Galaxy Note 4

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am currently working on an app using Cordova for Android however after testing it on a multitude of devices on Samsung's Galaxy Note 4 it is very unresponsive to touch events. I have added debugging statements for the debugging console and while the Touch is intercepted and I can even get the coordinates of the touch within the HTML element it takes multiple taps to trigger any response.

I wanted to ask have any of you experienced touch response issues on Cordova apps on Galaxy Note 4?

My software versions are as follows:
* Cordova 4.1.3 
* Latest Android SDK
* The device is running Android 4.4.4.

I will post code as needed.

Code posted below

```
console.log("LOG: UI Element tap detected on closest or favourites");
    var placesView = $("#places-view");
    var listItem = $(".locName");


    // see where our tap is intercepted.
    listItem.bind("touchstart", function (e) {
        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
        canvas_x = touch.pageX;
        canvas_y = touch.pageY;

        // now see where we get it 
        console.log("LOG: Touch Intercepted at "+canvas_x+" ,"+canvas_y);
    });
```

Comment: Code added to original post :)

Comment: As mentioned perhaps I was unclear but the touch interception work. However the event itself is not fired and the other view does not load. Except very rarely and i have to click all over the HTML element hoping it does fire. Anyway I will try your code and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @Shailendrsingh I have tried your code however it seems the on method is not recognised. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' functions.js:422
LOG: Slide left or right

Comment: Again the issue I had earlier with the method on() not being part of the html element object.

Comment: Let me check. I inherited the application from someone else. Apparently it is 1.6.2. I do not have any liberty to decide if to upgrade it or not. It is up to our lead dev.

Comment: Hei. This does exactly what my initial code did anyway. Right now I am trying to figure out why the actual view is not fired (except after tapping the screen alot) in varied places on the desired controls.

Comment: Not anything yet. Still looking into it as time and my other tasks permits.